# Graphics drivers and wifi not working after installing ubuntu

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless

I'm trying to get Ubuntu on a new machine. Neither my graphics drivers or my wifi is working. I need to handle the wifi before handling the graphics drivers, so I'm forced to do this from terminal.

I am not having a driver problem with my wifi. I could connect during the initial install, and could connect download things then, but does not connect automatically on real boots. **Right now wlan0 is  unknown**, but I have been able to make progress with the 'logical name' of my card used in place of that. **I have been able to scan for my network** with `sudo iw $logical_name scan | grep [SSID]`, so I think I'm close.

I've been following "Connect to WPA/WPA2 via terminal" things, and have been shut down in a few different places.

**Failer point 1:**

Editing `/etc/networking/interface` to read

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto <logical name spelled out>
iface <logical name spelled out> inet dhcp
wpa-ssid mynetworkname
wpa-psk mypassphrase
```

and calling `sudo ifup <logical name>` return "unknown interface ", same with wlan0. I have had another person double check the file for correctness.

**Failure Point 2**

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 wpa-ssid mynetworkname
sudo iwconfig wlan0 wpa-psk mypassphrase
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

called with wlan0 or logical name gives me ' iwconfig: unknown command "wpa-ssid" '

**EDIT 1**
@Jeremy31 asked why I wasn't using network manager. Answer: I didn't know about it.

nmcli g

```
STATE: disconnected
CONNECTIVITY: none
WIFI-HW: enabled
WIFI: enabled
WWAN: enabled
```

nmcli d

```
DEVICE: [logical name]
TYPE: wifi
STATE: disconnected
CONNECTION: --
```

**nmcli device wifi connect [SSID] password [pw]**

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (0) No reason given.
```

**Wifi Card**

*lsusb*

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:179d ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-N53 802.11abgn Network Adapter [Ralink RT3572]

*lshw -class network*

```
description: Wireless interface
physical id: 1
bus info: usb@1:2
logical name: wlxf46d045ddd3a
capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.4.0-51-generic firmware=0.29 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

Comment: Unfortunately, wi-fi on Linux is terribly complicated - unless you have a well known driver package for a well known hardware. Your device seems to be well-known. Now, how have you obtained the driver and firmware? Does it come from the official Ubuntu distribution? Otherwise it is Wild West.

Comment: Is this a server and that is why you are not using Network Manager?

Comment: ddbug, the drive and firmware are from default desktop 16.04 ISO DLed from canonical.  I bought the adapter specifically because amazon reviews say it plays nice with Ubuntu, and by and large it has until now. Even during the install process I could could get online

Jeremy31, I'm using the desktop build, but without working graphics drivers I might as well be.  I wasn't using network manage, but nmcli gives promising output. Please check question edits

Comment: I've set up wi-fi on my raspberry pi with Ubuntu 15.04 , which uses the `/etc/networking/interfaces` file, so I can dig it up and compare to yours, see what may be wrong.  Also, is connecting via Ethernet an option for you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

Thanks to @Jeremy31 I was pointed in the direction of network-manager / `nmcli`.

`nmcli con` gave me a list of connections, including the successful one from the install process. `nmcli -a con up [SSID]`  established an fully function connection.

Comment: Hi @Weavermount, You may mark your own answer as being "correct" if you are happy with it :)

Comment: Still in the two day wait to do that ;-)